# SQL Server Architecture for specific problem - full-text search - with full join

Tags: c#, full-text-search, sql-server-2008-r2

I am building an application that searches candidate's resumes.  I need to use full-text search on the application as there are a lot of records and the resume field is fairly large. The issue is that for advanced searches, I have another table RelocationItems,  that lists zips, states, etc. for the candidates relocation preferences and is related through a candidateID in the RelocationItems table.  The problem is that sometimes a candidate will have no RelocationItems, sometimes they will have one, and sometimes they will have more than one.  So, simple enough, I created a View that uses full outer join and then can select using DISTINCT on candidateID to find the candidates I need that will relocate to a certain area based on the search criteria.

The big problem with this view though as since it uses and Full Join, I can't use the full-text search now!  (obviously so because my full-text index field is now not a unique not-null field)

And my stored procedure has the CONTAINS word in it so it won't even compile.

Should I :
- Create a new table based on the view? (and then create another index identity field)
- Do something to store the relocation items in the candidate table (maybe an XML field)? (I don't think you can store a table-value parameter in 2008 can you?)
- Do some sort of Union of Tables (Queries)? (Run the search against the Candidates Table and then against the RelocationTable and then merge or union)?

Thanks for any suggestions on the best way to work around this problem!!!

Comment: I'm confused. Why can't you use full-text search on a view that has a full outer join? Why can't you compile a stored procedure with the word `CONTAINS` in it?

Comment: Hi Gabe - I wasn't able to compile the stored procedure because the SSMS said I was unable to use a full-text search on the query (it knew I was using FTS because of the 'CONTAINS').  When I looked at the structure of the View with the Join, it made sense as there is no unique non-nullable column anymore.  For any row that was a result of the match in the secondary table, my original index field from the first table was null (or duplicate, I can't remember, but either way it violated the FTS rules).

Comment: So you're saying that the resulting view did not contain enough information to be able to perform the full-text index lookup, then?

Comment: No, it had all of the information.  It was just that using the FTS predicate (I think that's the term) 'CONTAINS' requires a View that can use Full-Text Search.  I could have got the results from a regular Select statement.  So, the info is there but you can't use FTS as there is no non-nullable unique column.  I can't use a regular select as I need the FTS.

Answer (score 0):

> I created a View that uses full outer join and then can select using DISTINCT on candidateID to 
>   find the candidates I need that will relocate to a certain area based on the search criteria.

Already a potential problem - a subselect with exists would be better.

A properly set up query would have no problem - do not use a join, go for a subselect and exists.

Comment: That is an interesting approach I didn't know existed (no pun intented).  Thank you TomTom, I will give it a try!

Comment: Hey Tom Tom.. well, it compiled!!  I have yet to test it but thanks so much for the suggestion. I'll keep you posted as to the final results.